# Чтение имени файла средствами Python

Tags: python, файлы

Есть видео файл, нужно имя файла сохранить в переменную (для дальнейших преобразований), но сохранить нужно до расширения(.mp4). Как это сделать?

Comment: Используйте https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Файл лежит на диске (известно ли где конкретно?)  и нужно прочитать его имя? Или имя файла уже есть и нужно просто отбросить расширение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример с [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

file_name = 'C:/Users/111/video.mp4'
path = Path(file_name)
print(path.name)  # video.mp4
print(path.stem)  # video
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы имеете имя+расширение в переменной filename:

```
In[152]: filename = "some_video.mp4"
```

вы можете использовать модуль `os.path`:

```
In[151]: import os.path
In[153]: name, __ = os.path.splitext(filename)
In[154]: name
Out[154]: 'some_video'
```

В переменной __ будет расширение, но оно вам не нужно (потому такое чудесное имя):

```
In[155]: __
Out[155]: '.mp4'
```

Comment: А если `C:/Users/111/some_video.mp4`? :)

Comment: Попробуйте что-то типа name[name.rfind('/')+1, name.rfind('.')]

Answer (score 0):

```
from os.path import basename, splitext
name, ext = splitext(basename("C:/Users/111/some_video.mp4"))
print name
# 'some_video'
```